# import electron browser window in scala js

Tags: javascript, scala, scala.js

I want write below code in scala.js :

```
// In the main process.
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

// Or use `remote` from the renderer process.
// const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron').remote

let win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
win.on('closed', () => {
  win = null
})

// Load a remote URL
win.loadURL('https://github.com')

// Or load a local HTML file
win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/index.html`)
```

How can we do import electron and instantiate BrowserWindow in scala.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Scala.js 0.6.13+, you can choose to [emit CommonJS modules](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/project/module.html). When you do that, you can import `BrowserWindow` like this:

```scala
import scala.scalajs.js
import js.annotation._

@ScalaJSDefined
trait BrowserWindowOptions extends js.Object {
  def width: Double
  def height: Double
}

@js.native
@JSImport("electron", "BrowserWindow")
class BrowserWindow(options: BrowserWindowOptions) extends js.Object {
  ...
  def on(eventName: String, handler: js.Function0[Any]): Unit = js.native
  ...
}

var win = new BrowserWindow(new BrowserWindowOptions {
  val width = 800.0
  val height = 600.0
})
win.on("closed", { () =>
  win = null
})
```

Comment: I used the same code  but it is not identifying electron. 
I resolved the electron with require. but import is not working properly. 

please have a look at this image : http://imgur.com/a/HORwk

Comment: Make sure to `clean` your entire project and try again. If the problem persists, it's a Scala.js bug. Try to minimize it and report it.

Comment: i uploaded my code into github : https://github.com/rajeevprasanna/CloudManagerApp

Please have a look at this.... it has one scala class and build class

Comment: Definitely a bug. Please report it on GitHub: https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues

Comment: As identified by @julienrf on GitHub, the build configuration is missing its `scalaJSModuleKind := ModuleKind.CommonJSModule`.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to update the `.gitignore` file to prevent it becomes to messy on GitHub. Take a standard scala.js .gitignore file and get rid of the dot (hidden) files. Except .gitignore of course. `build.sbt` will reconstruct to whole project, so there absolutely no need push .idea files. The same applies to the `node_modules` and `target` directories. They are thrash and noise for me, you and others. Especially for people who has an other IDE. Please tidy up the GitHub repository.

Actually only `/src/main/scala/CloudConnectionComponent.scala` `.gitignore`, `build.sbt`and `project/build.properties' /`project/plugins.sbt` should appear on GitHub.

Comment: I agree with you.. I will add them to gitignore and remove noise.